# Flag whenever there is change in business

Tags: sql

Data #TRAN

```
ID                          Business              STDT      
501                         50005038             20170208             
501                         50005038             20170801
501                         50005035             20170802
501                         50005038             20171101
501                         50005038             20180101
501                         50005035             20180201
514                         50005038             20170208
514                         50005038             20170423
514                         50005038             20170801
514                         50005038             20170801
514                         50005035             20170802
514                         50005038             20171101
514                         50005035             20171201
```

I am trying to flag those event where Business Code is changing. I tried the below mention query, 
however the result I'am getting shows previous Business Code as well. I would like the query where it flags only the changed Business Code rows

I have tried this query

Code:

```
with cte as 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ID order by STDT) as rn
from #TRAN
)

,cte1 as
(
select c1.ID, c1.Business as S1, c1.STDT as T1, c2.Business as S2, c2.STDT as T2, c1.[], c1.
from cte c1 join cte c2
       on c1.rn + 1 = c2.rn
          and c1.ID = c2.ID
where c1.Business <> c2.Business
)

select ID,[], ,
       case n 
              when 1 then S1
              when 2 then S2
       end as Business_Code,
       case n 
              when 1 then T1
              when 2 then T2
       end as Timestamp
from cte1 cross join (select 1 n union all select 2) nums
order by ID, [Timestamp];
```

Result I'am getting-->

```
ID            Business              Timestamp
501         50005038             20170801
501         50005035             20170802
501         50005035             20170802
501         50005038             20171101
501         50005038             20180101
501         50005035             20180201
514         50005038             20170801
514         50005035             20170802
514         50005035             20170802
514         50005038             20171101
514         50005038             20171101
```

Result I would like-->

```
ID                          Business              STDT                      Flag
501                         50005038             20170208             
501                         50005038             20170801
501                         50005035             20170802             1
501                         50005038             20171101             1
501                         50005038             20180101
501                         50005035             20180201             1
514                         50005038             20170208
514                         50005038             20170423
514                         50005038             20170801
514                         50005038             20170801
514                         50005035             20170802             1
514                         50005038             20171101             1
514                         50005035             20171201             1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select 
    t.*,
    case 
        when not (
            business = coalesce(lag(business) over(partition by id order by stdt), business)
        )
        then 1
    end
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2cb307bfd74907be99739ace9b2c1b1)**:

```
 ID | Business |     STDT | (No column name)
--: | -------: | -------: | ---------------:
501 | 50005038 | 20170208 |             null
501 | 50005038 | 20170801 |             null
501 | 50005035 | 20170802 |                1
501 | 50005038 | 20171101 |                1
501 | 50005038 | 20180101 |             null
501 | 50005035 | 20180201 |                1
514 | 50005038 | 20170208 |             null
514 | 50005038 | 20170423 |             null
514 | 50005038 | 20170801 |             null
514 | 50005038 | 20170801 |             null
514 | 50005035 | 20170802 |                1
514 | 50005038 | 20171101 |                1
514 | 50005035 | 20171201 |                1
```

Answer (score 1):

GMB's answer is fine, but it can be simplified to:

```
select t.*,
       (case when business = lag(business) over (partition by id order by stdt)
             then null else 1
        end) as flag
from mytable t;
```